# Is there a way to show the linter status in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I just had an issue with my Python linter (Pylama) where it was crashing, but VSCode didn't show any indication of that, even in the "Python output" (`python.viewOutput`). Only when I ran it manually in the terminal did I find out there was a issue. So is there a way to have VSCode tell me if a linter crashes?

Next, after fixing the issue, the linter takes a long time to run, and while it's running it removes any "problems", which is confusing, because the problems haven't gone away, it just hasn't found them yet. So is there a way to have VSCode show that the the linter is running?

If it's relevant, I'm using VSCodium with Jedi (though I don't think Jedi is involved here).

I googled `vscode linter status`, checked [Linting Python in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting), and searched "status" and "linter" in the settings but didn't see anything relevant.

If it helps, the full command line in the "Python output" is:
`~/Programs/anaconda3/bin/conda run -p ~/Programs/miniconda3/envs/anaconda3_11 --no-capture-output python ~/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.6.1-universal/pythonFiles/get_output_via_markers.py ~/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.6.1-universal/pythonFiles/linter.py -m pylama --options=.pylama.ini ./tmp_ana.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the Go extension shows the linter status (according to [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/1456)), so it's possible, but the Python extension doesn't do it.

Checking the source code seems to confirm that: The file that runs the linter, [`linter.py`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/main/pythonFiles/linter.py), doesn't check the return status (from `subprocess.run`). And I assume whatever code ultimately runs `linter.py` doesn't add a status bar icon while it's running.

Lastly, I'm not sure why stderr isn't shown in the "Python output". Maybe it's intercepted by something along the way, i.e. one of the wrappers shown there (`conda run` or `get_output_via_markers.py`).

So, I suppose I'll be submitting a feature request to the Python extension

Comment: do add a link here to your issue ticket once you've created it :)